# Escaping '?' in mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

The tail end of my .htaccess reads:

```
RewriteCond %{query_string} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/\?iframe x_iframe.php?pageurl=$1&%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{query_string} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ x.php?pageurl=$1&%1 [L]
```

What I'm trying to do is have it so that any URL ending in '?iframe' uses a different page.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only test the current [URL path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax) with the [`RewriteRule` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). The URL query can only be tested with the [`RewriteCond` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^iframe$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ x_iframe.php?pageurl=$1 [L]
```